# Cosa vuol dire "a saltabecco"?

Tags: meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La nascita del giullare* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> Venite qui... è il tempo e il luogo che io faccia il pagliaccio per voi! Tutti intorno a me! Venite! V'insegno un modo nuovo di stare al mondo. Venite... venite! Attenti che sgambetti e lazzi v'improvviso... una cantatina, e faccio pure i falsetti **a saltabecco**!

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "a saltabecco" in questo brano. Ho cercato il vocabolo "saltabecco", ma non l'ho trovato in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine dialettale? Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "a saltabecco" in questo passaggio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Saltabeccare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/saltabeccare/) significa saltare avanti come una cavalletta, ma in senso figurato vuol dire

> con uso estens. e fig., passare a rapidi salti da luogo a luogo, da
> gruppo a gruppo, da un ragionamento all’altro, o sim.

Nel passaggio da te indicato vuol significare che il cantante poteva fare cambiamenti improvvisi di tono e di ritmo con la sua voce, cantando in falsetto.